# Chat API question about spaces and members

Tags: google-api, chat, google-workspace, google-hangouts

I have an account with the admin access so I can see and manage all the spaces from the admin GUI.
But when I use Chat API to retrieve all the spaces, I only get the spaces within my account.
I did the Oauth2 authentication with the same account.
So how can I get all the spaces from my organization?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.